# Dictionaries pointing to another dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary `dic = {k: v}`. My goal is to create another data structure that will point to a subset of a dictionary, accessed under a single key.

E.g: `dic = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'f'}`. 
I would like a pointer only to keys `1` and `3`, for instance, but retrievable under a single key `'k1'`, and to keys `2` and `4` retrievable under a single key `'k2'` without the need to do a hardcopy. My data won't change throughout the application.

I know I can create another dictionary `subdic = {'k1': (a, c), 'k2': (b, f)}`, but that would require extra memory, right? 
How can I do that only with some sort of pointers? With a softcopy, such that values are only once in memory from the original dictionary `dic`.

Comment: Can you give a non-prose (that is, code) example of how you would access this and what the output should be? Maybe how you create it as well. I'm not following your notation as is.

Comment: I think it is quite clear. What you do not get? Dictionary creation?

Comment: Well... you're asking in a Python question about how to make a pointer, which is C (and related) not Python, and something about another dict requiring extra memory... OK, well pointers require extra memory as well... What kind of (Python) object do you want and how do you expect it to behave? The stupid answer to your question is if you want some kind of multi-dict using pointers you'll have to write your own C extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a second dictionary like this

```
dic2 = {'k1': (dic[1], dic[3])}
```

Doing so, you don't actually use extra memory (only marginally) because the objects in the tuple are the same as the ones in your original `dic` (they occupy the same space in memory). You can check that it is true by doing:

```
id(dic2['k1'][0]) == id(dic[1]) # True
```